# External Hard Drive died – How do I recover those files from Time Machine?

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, backup, external-disk, data-recovery

My external hard drive, which I was backing up with Time Machine, finally died. I want to retrieve some of those files, but when I go into Time Machine I can't navigate to those files because Time Machine does not show the drive.

I have examined the "Backups.backupdb" folder and can see that the associated drive still exists within the Time Machine backup, but I am having difficulty navigating to files (for some reason items within folders will just "disappear").

How can I recover my files?

Comment: Have you purchased and hooked up a new external drive with the same name as the one which died and attempted to restore files?

Comment: I'm looking to do the same no luck yet...try this

http://superuser.com/questions/65146/how-to-restore-a-failed-external-hard-drive-from-time-machine